# Spring Social : OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social, scribe, spring-social-facebook

Can any one help me on this, please

I get the following exception when I try to parse Facebook token, using spring social

> org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect.
>   Can't extract a token from this:

This is my code :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String postOnWall(@RequestParam("code") String code,
                             @RequestParam("state") String state, HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        OAuthService oAuthService = facebookServiceProvider.getService();
        Verifier verifier = new Verifier(code);

        Token accessToken = oAuthService
                .getAccessToken(Token.empty(), verifier); // here is the error

        FacebookTemplate template = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken.getToken());
        String userId = template.userOperations().getUserProfile().getId();

        Logger.logInfo(this.getClass(), "Logged in User Id : {}" + userId);

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = facebookUtil
                .publishLinkWithVisiblityRestriction(state);
        try {
            template.publish(userId,"feed", map);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.logError(this.getClass(),
                    "Exception Occurred while posting a link on facebook for user Id : {}, exception is : {}",
                    ex);
            return PUBLISH_ERROR;
        }
        return PUBLISH_SUCCESS;
    }
```

I get the error on this line of code

```
Token accessToken = oAuthService
                .getAccessToken(Token.empty(), verifier);
```

this is my pom.xml

```
 <!-- Spring Social -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
            <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

full Exception :

```
02-Sep-2018 01:53:40.113 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [action-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this: '{"access_token":"tkL7oLZCXeqasLloDyiToMp5nVaK7vSFveDc3M60sk7VmcHD8XsSdcpPtlZBBZAN7fKGlSZBgLdL9zoEnu3NyMVMZAZB2ERCAhm64YEiR5oRLuc1lIHZBOwlDkuJxIt7lJmHVO8d","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5182686}'] with root cause
 org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this: '{"access_token":"tkL7oLZCXeqasLloDyiToMp5nVaK7vSFveDc3M60sk7VmcHD8XsSdcpPtlZBBZAN7fKGlSZBgLdL9zoEnu3NyMVMZAZB2ERCAhm64YEiR5oRLuc1lIHZBOwlDkuJxIt7lJmHVO8d","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5182686}'
    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractor20Impl.extract(TokenExtractor20Impl.java:33)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth20ServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth20ServiceImpl.java:37)
    at com.test.controller.FacebookController.postOnWall(FacebookController.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a really old version of `scribe` that expects the token response in a completely different format!

The newest version is [`5.5.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.scribejava/scribejava-apis) and not [`1.3.2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scribe/scribe) (the second link points you to the later version, with a changed `groupId` and `artifactId`.

The [example they provide](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/wiki/Getting-Started) is one way to solve your problem. [Spring also](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_simple) has the necessary tools to be able to do this.